# Jquery Total Size of all upload file - reset size after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a jquery code to restrict the size of individual upload files to specific size (like 1Mb), and also to restrict the sum size of all upload files to specific amount (like 5 MB), which means that you can upload as many files as you want as long as the size of individual file is not larger than 1Mb, and total size of all files must be less than 5Mb. I'm beginner in JQuery so every help is good. My code below works, but the problem is that when total size exeeds the set max it throws an alert, but the size of the file is still included in total which means you cannot add a smaller file that would fit inside of a limit. I would need to reset it somehow to check it every time. I searched through everything but cannot figure it out.

$(document).on("change", "input[type=file]",function () {

```
var file = this.files[0];

if (file.size > 200*1024) {
    alert("The file is too large. Maximum file size of individual file is 5 MB.");
    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="file">');
    return false;
}
```

});

```
 var total = 0;


 $(document).on("change", "input[type=file]", function(){                            

for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){  

    total = total + this.files[i].size; 

}

   if(total>250*1024){

alert("Total size too big: " + total);
   $(this).replaceWith('<input type="file">');
    return false;
   }
```

});

Comment: Move the if condition inside the for loop, so it checks for the total size on the go, if the total is greater than the limit, remove that last added file size from the total

Comment: Thanks, it works :) The only thing is that now the last value is removed, but I am not able to replace other file and exclude that value from the total.